Postgres with RepMgr and PGPool, how to restart the cluster without loosing synchronization
We have a 2 VM setup (server1 and server2), with a Postgres 15.6 database on each server.
Each VM has also a PGPool instance with Watchdog and there is one shared IP. Repmgr (15) is used for data replication. Replication and automatic failover work both as expected.
In its calm state the status of the cluster is like this:
#### REPLICATION STATUS ##################

 ID | Name              | Role    | Status    | Upstream          | repmgrd | PID     | Paused? | Upstream last seen
----+-------------------+---------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------
 1  | Postgres 15 - PG1 | primary | * running |                   | running | 3863359 | no      | n/a
 2  | Postgres 15 - PG2 | standby |   running | Postgres 15 - PG1 | running | 23472   | no      | 0 second(s) ago

#### PGPOOL STATUS #######################

 node_id | hostname | port | status | pg_status | lb_weight |  role   | pg_role | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | replication_state | replication_sync_state | last_status_change
---------+----------+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------
 0       | server1  | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | primary | primary | 0          | true              | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-09-02 10:57:01
 1       | server2  | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | standby | standby | 0          | false             | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-09-02 10:57:01
(2 rows)

#### PGPOOL WATCHDOG #####################

Leader PGPool details:
2 2 NO server2:9999 Linux CONPG2 server2

server1:9999 Linux CONPG1 server1 9999 9000 7 STANDBY 0 MEMBER
server2:9999 Linux CONPG2 server2 9999 9000 4 LEADER 0 MEMBER

One requirement that came recently from a customer is that they want to patch and reboot the servers monthly. I am trying to understand what is the best way (or sequence) to stop the services on the cluster, so after the reboot everything works again.
No matter what I tried, I always end up with this:
#### REPLICATION STATUS ##################

WARNING: node "Postgres 15 - PG2" not found in "pg_stat_replication"
 ID | Name              | Role    | Status    | Upstream            | repmgrd | PID     | Paused? | Upstream last seen
----+-------------------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+--------------------
 1  | Postgres 15 - PG1 | primary | * running |                     | running | 3875259 | no      | n/a
 2  | Postgres 15 - PG2 | standby |   running | ! Postgres 15 - PG1 | running | 1061842 | no      | 0 second(s) ago

WARNING: following issues were detected
  - node "Postgres 15 - PG2" (ID: 2) is not attached to its upstream node "Postgres 15 - PG1" (ID: 1)

#### PGPOOL STATUS #######################

 node_id | hostname | port | status | pg_status | lb_weight |  role   | pg_role | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | replication_state | replication_sync_state | last_status_change
---------+----------+------+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------+---------------------
 0       | server1  | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | primary | primary | 0          | true              | 0                 |                   |                        | 2024-09-02 11:36:32
 1       | server2  | 5432 | up     | up        | 0.500000  | standby | standby | 0          | false             | 16786288          |                   |                        | 2024-09-02 11:36:32
(2 rows)

#### PGPOOL WATCHDOG #####################

Leader PGPool details:
2 2 YES server1:9999 Linux CONPG1 server1

server1:9999 Linux CONPG1 server1 9999 9000 4 LEADER 0 MEMBER
server2:9999 Linux CONPG2 server2 9999 9000 7 STANDBY 0 MEMBER

The standby database has lost the sync(?):

WARNING: following issues were detected

node "Postgres 15 - PG2" (ID: 2) is not attached to its upstream node "Postgres 15 - PG1" (ID: 1)


When I try to tell the standby to follow, unregister-register, rejoin, pg_reqind, I'm always getting this:

WARNING: node "Postgres 15 - PG2" not found in "pg_stat_replication"

Same when I tried was to pause/unpause repmgr.
The only way forward is to clone the standby again and that may take time for a huge database. Is there a way to stop the cluster and start it without getting that WARNING???
Edit: the applications connecting to this database are stopped, so there is no read/write happening
